# Pizza box and lunch box in SMBIOS: What are they?

Tags: bios, hardware

The SMBIOS spec lists Pizza Box (05h) and Lunch Box (10h) as the meaning for System Enclosure or Chassis Types. The other stuff makes sense but these do not. Are there really chassis types that corresponds to these types? If so, could someone please point out examples for them.

Comment: John - there's no single manufacturer, the SMBIOS is an industry spec.

Answer (score 4):

They probably refer to the form factors used by workstations of yesteryear such as the [Sun SPARCstation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARCstation) line. "Pizza boxes" were flat and squareish and "lunch boxes" were small, squat, and about the size of the metal lunch boxes used by schoolkids in the U.S. from the 60's to the 80's. I dimly recall external drive enclosures being called "shoeboxes".

Comment: Believe it or not, this is indeed accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Both are actually desktop form factors.  The pizza box happens to be ~1U in height, but is -not- the same form factor as a a modern 1U server.  The lunchbox is, as mentioned above, akin to the shape of a child's metal lunchbox (but does not share its dimensions).

These are the classic examples of both form factors -

[Pizza Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARCstation_10)

[Lunch Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARCstation_IPC)

Answer (score 1):

As several people noted, "Pizza Box" refers to a 1U server.

"Lunch Box" refers to a portable computer inside a transportable case vaguely resembling a child's lunch box. This type of computer usually has a keyboard and display that pop out of the case somehow. These are typically used in military applications.

Comment: Something like a KVM used in racks nowadays but only larger/bulkier perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of Lunch Box, but Pizza Box is indeed a real thing. It's a 1U server for a 19" rack. They call it a pizza box because it's not very deep and fairly square, somewhat resembling a ... pizza box.

Comment: Same here. Refering to a 1U server that is roughly as deep as it is wide as a pizzabox is fairly common. Never encountered lunchbox either, but it could refer to Ultra Small Formfactor desktops (like e.g a Lenovo A61e). Or networked media-players, various game-consoles, nas, etc. that come in small enclosures.

Comment: Did some more reading - it's not just server-specific, so there were pizzabox PowerMacs and SPARCStations, and a Lunchbox is like a laptop with a hunchback. A "luggable".